# Does the wordpress XML RPC interface offer token based authentication?

Tags: web-services, security, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm looking at the [wordpress XML RPC documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp) and it seems that the username and password are required in the plain on every request.

Is there a token based alternative to this to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to expose the xmlrpc service only over ssl.